# Shipping Method TABLE RATES i

Tags: magento, magento2

Shipping Method TABLE RATES not showing on checkout page.

here is my admin side setting screenshot: http://prntscr.com/f4v4ic

My CSV layout and values screenshot:

Please suggestion any solution http://prntscr.com/f4v9ka

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be due to a number of reasons i.e. If you are selecting USA as the country in the checkout AND the total weight is less than 0.1, you will not see a shipping method as none match the criteria.

I suggest placing a new row in your CSV for testing purposes:

```
Country    Region/State    Zip/Postal Code    Weight     Shipping Price
  *             *              *                *             10
```

This means no matter the destination, the shipping price will be $10. If this appears then the functionality is working fine and your CSV is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Today I just find out that products do not have any weight and appropriate country that's why it was not showing the module